# Track files when parent folder is ignored in .gitignore

Tags: git, bitbucket, gitignore

So I have /vendor in gitignore and want to exclude some files in subfolders but it won't work, they are still being ignored. Checked git documentation, some threads here and still no luck, any idea what I'm missing?

This is what I got:

```
vendor
!vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php
!vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php
```

Comment: According to the documentation at https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore for Pattern Format for the ! character: 
"It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded."

Comment: Why do you need to not ignore a file from `vendor`?

Answer (score 4):

You can force add them once using `git add -f`, and they will afterward remain tracked within the repo:

```
git add -f vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php
git add -f vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/ResetsPasswords.php
```

As mentioned by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49666863/exclude-files-from-git-ignore-bitbucket-wont-work#comment86343772_49666863) in comment, as per [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore),

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are defined.

This is also clear if you try to use `check-ignore` on the file foe identifying which rule is ignoring the files:

```
Test $ mkdir -p vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords && touch vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php

Test $ cat .gitignore 
vendor
!vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php

Test $ git check-ignore -v vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php
.gitignore:1:vendor vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php

Test $ git add vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Passwords/PasswordBroker.php
Use -f if you really want to add them.
```